# How to Edit only required fields from database collection (azure Cosmosdb) using C# in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to edit CosmosDb collection using C# in ASP.NET MVC. It's editing given fields correctly but deleting fields which are not in form.

**My controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditAsync([Bind(Include = "Id, DeviceId,GroupId,IPaddress,Name,Address,Lat,DeviceTypeId, DeviceModelId, Long, UserName, Password, PhoneNo, IMEI,PUK, SimPin, SpeedLimit, ActivationSpeed, SpeedLog, EnvLog, Status")] Editdevice item)//LastContact.Ping, LastContact.Voltage, LastContact.EnLog, LastContact.SpdLog, 
{ 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await DocumentDBRepository<Editdevice>.UpdateDeviceAsync(item.Id, item);
        return RedirectToAction("EditIndex");
    }
               
    return View(item);
}

[ActionName("Edit")]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditAsync(int GroupId, string id)
{
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "ChainZone", Value = "1" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Particle", Value = "2" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Raspberry Pi", Value = "3" });

    ViewBag.Type = items;
       
    var DeviceModel = await DocumentDBRepository<Devicemodel>.GetDeviceModelAsync(d => d.Id != null);
    // var  selectList = 
    ViewBag.Model = DeviceModel.ToList();

    //   string DId = DeviceId.ToString();
    //   var item = await DocumentDBRepository<EditDevice>.GeteditDeviceAsync(d => d.DeviceId == DId);

    var item = await DocumentDBRepository<Editdevice>.GeteditDeviceAsync(GroupId, id);

    return View(item);
}
```

Collection before saving Edit is:

```
{
"id": "93607e3f-9e99-4f74-9f54-5f3306bf3fea",
"Long": "153.359726",
"IPaddress": "192.168.2.180",
"SpeedLog": true,
"DeviceModelId": 16,
"Address": "10 A.B. Paterson Drive, Arundel, Qld",
"Lat": "-27.927782",
"EnvLog": true,
"Name": "A.B. Paterson College, Sign 1. FULL MATRIX FTP [2-180]",
"DeviceTypeId": 1,
"RoadSpeedLimit": 20,
"ActivationSpeed": 20,
"DeviceId": "51",
"UserName": "hvswireless171@hvsigns.com.au",
"Password": "hvs171",
"PhoneNo": null,
"IMEI": "8000 0860 1049 5N",
"Puk": null,
"SimPin": null,
"LastContact": {
    "EnvLog": "2020-06-12T11:52:10",
    "Ping": "2020-06-12T03:10:28",
    "Voltage": 12.28,
    "SpdLog": "2020-06-12T11:52:10"
},
"Sensors": [
    1,
    3
],
"GroupId": 28,
"_rid": "sklTANWqGFAUAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/sklTAA==/colls/sklTANWqGFA=/docs/sklTANWqGFAUAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"00006af1-0000-1a00-0000-5ee308170000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1591937047
}
```

after saving edit it is:

```
{
"id": "93607e3f-9e99-4f74-9f54-5f3306bf3fea",
"Long": "153.359726",
"IPaddress": "192.168.2.180",
"SpeedLog": true,
"DeviceModelId": 16,
"Address": "10 A.B. Paterson Drive, Arundel, Qld",
"Lat": "-27.927782",
"EnvLog": true,
"Name": "A.B. Paterson College, Sign 1. FULL MATRIX FTP [2-180]",
"DeviceTypeId": 1,
"RoadSpeedLimit": 20,
"ActivationSpeed": 20,
"DeviceId": "51",
"UserName": "hvswireless171@hvsigns.com.au",
"Password": "hvs171",
"PhoneNo": null,
"IMEI": "8000 0860 1049 5N",
"Puk": null,
"SimPin": null,
"GroupId": 28,
"_rid": "sklTANWqGFAUAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/sklTAA==/colls/sklTANWqGFA=/docs/sklTANWqGFAUAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"00006af1-0000-1a00-0000-5ee308170000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1591937047
}
```

Please help. How can I just edit few fields and leave the others as they are? It has many fields which don't need to be edited. But they are vanishing or set as null after submitting edit form.

Comment: @Jawad can you please help

Comment: @derloopkat can you please help?